# Detect access to freed unnamed temporary

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, temporary, c++98

If class `B` has a constructor that accepts a reference to an object of class `A` stores that reference, and is called with a temporary of that class, the reference seems to become invalid after the constructor finishes (see [example run](http://codepad.org/NrzKRsZP)). However, none of the static code analysis tools I tried detected this condition:

- `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`
- `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`
- `cppcheck`
- `clang-tidy`
- CLion's integrated inspections

I think I understand that the compiler's behavior conforms to the standard. How to detect such code in an existing codebase? Which programming conventions can help avoiding such hard-to-catch errors?

Full example code and annotated output below for completeness.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  explicit A(int i) : i_(i) { std::cerr << this << " A\n"; }
  ~A() { std::cerr << this << " ~A\n"; }

  void do_() const { std::cerr << this << " " << i_ << "\n"; }

private:
  int i_;
};

class B {
public:
  explicit B(const A& a) : a_(a) { std::cerr << this << " B\n"; }
  ~B() { std::cerr << this << " ~B\n"; }
  void do_() const { std::cerr << this << " "; a_.do_(); }

  const A& a_;
};

int main(int, char**) {
  B b(A(42));
  int i = 0;
  b.do_();
  std::cerr << i << " main\n";
}
```

Output:

```
# Construction of b
0xffa66138 A
0xffa66134 B
0xffa66138 ~A
# Calling b.do_()
0xffa66134 0xffa66138 42
# Printing i in main()
0 main
# End of main()
0xffa66134 ~B
```

Comment: Simply search for classes that contain references as member variables - that's almost always not what you want. A regex should be able to find most cases.

Comment: I would just forbid reference members in classes.

Comment: Even if you forbid/prevent temporaries wouldn't you still have issues if an object of `B` outlives the referenced object of `A` (dangling reference)?

Answer (score 2):

You may forbid temporary with deleted constructor

```
class B {
public:
    explicit B(const A& a) : a_(a) { std::cerr << this << " B\n"; }
    B(A&&) = delete;
// ...
};
```

A way to guaranty that lifetime of `A` is longer than `B` would be to take a `shared_ptr`.